# Difference between Object.getPrototypeOf(x) and x.constructor.prototype?

Tags: javascript

For most values of `x` that I have tested, the following evaluates to `true`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === x.constructor.prototype
```

...but there are a few exceptions: if `x` is a string, the LHS of the expression above fails with an error like

```
TypeError: "abc" is not an object
```

...although, e.g., `"abc".constructor.prototype` evaluates to `String.prototype`.  One gets analogous results if `x` is a number or a boolean.

What's going on?  Are there more exceptions to the identity shown earlier?

More to the point, the above suggests that `x.constructor.prototype` is more robust than `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)`.

Is there any good reason *not* to use `x.constructor.prototype` exclusively and forget entirely about the `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)`?

Answer (score 1):

Strings (and other primitives) can behave a little weirdly.

Basically, when you try to access a property of a primitive, it is boxed in a Just-In-Time fashion using its Object equivalent, and then the property of that object is returned.

So in this case, when you try to access `"abc".constructor`, what's actually happening is the same as `new String("abc").constructor` (which of course returns the `String` object).

On the other hand, `Object.getPrototypeOf` does no such boxing, instead returning an error if you pass it anything that isn't an object.

As you suggest, `x.constructor.prototype` does seem to be a more reliable method of determining the constructor of something, since it does handle this "boxing" case. That said, personally I can't think of any real situation where something like this might be needed, since... well, typically, you already know what type something is. It's the same reason I don't see any real point in using `===` most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Object.getPrototypeOf is not supported by older browsers where as x.constructor.prototype is more cross-browser solution.

However, if available it is more reliable to use Object.getPrototypeOf because x.constructor can be changed like so: x.constructor = 'my new value';

I suggest you to create this polyfill function:

```
if (!Object.getPrototypeOf) {
    Object.getPrototypeOf = function(o) { return o.__proto__ || o.constructor.prototype; };
}
```